# Laravel 4 Form Model Binding with Dynamic Form Not Properly Filling In

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel-4, model-binding

I am having trouble getting a dynamic form to properly load. I have a form that a user can click a button and add input fields to their hearts content. I have been able to json_encode and store the information but when I try to edit the form Laravel only creates and fills in the default inputs, leaving out the input fields and data created by the user. How can I get Laravel's form model-binding to display the additional fields and information? Or am I just form model-binding incorrectly? The user can push "Add Another Fence" and another copy of the form is added to the bottom. So, in this case (I didn't include the entire form because it is very long), they could press the "Add Another Fence" button and another input with class "gateNumber" and a newly created id of "gateNumber_2" would appear at the bottom. If anyone knows how to get the dynamic data to bind and display or point out where I am going wrong it will be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Here is my Routes for the edit:

```
/*Edit Orders (GET)*/
Route::get('orders/{orders}/edit', array(
    'as'    => 'order-edit',
    'uses'  => 'OrderController@getEdit'
));
/*Edit Order (POST)*/
    Route::post('/orders/{orders}/edit', array(
    'as'    => 'order-edit-post',
        'uses'  => 'OrderController@postEdit',
    ));
```

View (or at least a snippet, the form is very long):

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')
{{ Form::model($order, array('route'=>array('order-edit-post', $order->id), 'name', '=', 'orderForm', 'id', '=', 'orderForm')) }}
 <fieldset id="customerInfo">
     {{ Form::label('order_name', 'Order Name:')}}
     {{ Form::text('order_name') }}
        @if($errors->has('order_name'))
    {{ $errors->first('order_name') }}
    @endif
<legend><strong>Gate Information</strong></legend>
    {{ Form::select('gateNumber_1',
        array(
            'select'    => 'Gates Needed',
            '0'         => '0',
            '1'         => '1',
            '2'         => '2',
            '3'         => '3',
    ), null,
    array('class'       => 'gateNumber')) }}
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAddFence" value="Add Another Fence" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDelFence" value="Remove Fence" />
</div>
```

And Order Controller:

```
public function getEdit($id){
        $order = Order::where('id', '=', $id);

        if($order->count()) {
            $order = $order->first();
            $order->order_serialized = json_decode($order->order_serialized);

            foreach($order->order_serialized as $key => $value){
                $order->$key = $value;
            }
            return View::make('orders.edit')
                    ->with('order', $order);
        }   else {
            return App::abort(404);
        }
    }

    public function postEdit($id){
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
            array(
                'order_name'            =>'required',
                'phone'                 =>'required|min:10|numeric',
                'email'                 =>'required',
                'st_address'            =>'required',
                'post_date'             =>'required',
            )           
        );

        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::route('order-edit', $id)
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput()
                    ->with('global', 'You done messed up.');
        }   else {
            /*Edit Order*/
            $order                      = Order::find($id);

            $order->order_name          = Input::get('order_name');
            $order->phone               = Input::get('phone');
            $order->email               = Input::get('email');
            $order->st_address          = Input::get('st_address');
            $order->post_date           = Input::get('post_date');
            $order->order_serialized    = json_encode(Input::except('_token', 'submit'));

            if($order->save()){
                return Redirect::route('home')
                        ->with('global', 'Your order has been edited.');
            }
        }

        return Redirect::route('home')
                ->with('global', 'Your order could not be edited.');

    }
```

Comment: Your gateNumber_2 is added via javascript or you do a new request to create them? The relevant part, the creation of your new selects is missing...

Comment: It is created by Javascript, I know that it works so I figured it wasn't relevant to figuring out how to get Laravel to fully bind the form but I will put it up.

Comment: Dang it, it won't let me edit the question, but here is the code:
`$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnAddFence').click(function () {
var num = $('.inputFence').length;
var newElem = $('.inputFence:last').clone();
$('.inputFence:last').after(newElem);
 $('#btnDelFence').removeAttr('disabled');
 var parts = $('.fenceHeight:last').attr('name').split("_");
$('.fenceHeight:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));
parts = $('.footage:last').attr('name').split("_");
    parts[1]++;
    $('.footage:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

var newElem = $('.inputFence:last').clone();

Comment: I repeat the parts = ... through the $('.footage:last').attr... lines for each input. In short it for each input grabs each input by class, divides the id at the "_", adds one to the number at the end of the id, rejoins the two parts, adds them in a newly created div at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel binds data to your form when you use:

```
{{ Form::model($order, ...) }}
```

and

```
{{ Form::text('order_name') }}
```

But inside your javascript, you're not using the latter to create those new fields.

Anyway, this is something you could not do via Javascript, you have to execute it in PHP (Laravel). But you can, via ajax, gather this information from your database.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I appreciate it!